# Window 10 hangs when running a flutter project in Android studio.{using laptop with 8 gb RAM}

Tags: windows, android-studio, flutter, freeze, flutter-test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qtlE.jpg)

From last one day when Iam trying to run a flutter project my laptop hangs. It was working fine earlier.

Comment: It is best not to use screen captures but to cut and paste the error into your question using code tags.  That aside have you check that your laptop meets the min required spec for both Android Studio and Flutter?

Comment: Check your internet connection and try to stop and rerun your app. If not solved, run `flutter clean` and rebuild your app

Comment: Today I came to know that the  problem is with the specific project. All other projects are working fine